# Time Format Validation

Tags: time, vb6

User Entering the Time Value in the Masked Textbox

For Example

User Enter Time like 08:00 (HH:MM)

User Enter Time like 28:00 (HH:MM) , Textbox should not accept this value.  Because it should accept from 00 to 23 (HH) and 00 to 59 (MM).

How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Validate Event](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson5/p7.html) - you can test the value in this event and correct it or error appropriately (depending on what user experience you would like)

```
Private Sub txtDate_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsDate(txtdate.Text) Then
        'fix it here OR
        Cancel = True 'don't allow the input
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231249%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) instead of the MaskedTextBox? DateTimePicker was specifically designed for allowing the user to enter time values. Set the `CustomFormat` to "HH:MM"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the masked textbox to range check the values as it can't be checked using a format string.
You can however use the IsDate() and/or CDate() functions to check and convert to a valid date/time.

```
?isdate("08:00")
True
?cdate("08:00")
08:00:00 
?isdate("28:00")
False
```